# How to fix Figure Caption automatic Numbers when placing Section Breaks?

Tags: formatting, figure, sections, page-break, word-2016

I'm trying to make sections at Word 2016 with Nex Page Breaks and I need to insert images (aka figures for APA Style), and I need to include caption on them.
Caption is auto generated, but at some points, when I insert the next page break, the Caption numeration is screwed, like figure 5 is figure 6 and figure 6 is 5 (and that is reflected at my Figures Index).
I have tried normal break, using top and bottom selection on pictures, but it does not work.
What should I do?
Thanks!.

Comment: This is not a programming question; it's an end-user one and, as such, is off-topic here. That said, you can either group the figures and captions, or you can put both in a wrapped table.

Comment: I know it is not a programming question, but since stackoverflow allow the word tags, I thought It would be a good place to look for help.

Comment: As is stated quite clearly at the top of this forum: *For programming questions related to Microsoft's "Word" editor. Questions on general usage of the editor are off-topic for Stack Overflow; they should be asked on Super User instead.*